How to fake a LocalCertificate in ASP.NET Core integration tests?
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core project, and I need to write an integration test that involves using SSL certificates. Specifically, I want to fake the LocalCertificate property in the integration test. Here's the relevant part of the code that I'm trying to test:
var localCertificate = context.Features?.Get<ISslStreamFeature>()?.SslStream.LocalCertificate as X509Certificate2;

This localCertificate is retrieved during the request processing, and I want to mock or fake it during my integration test to simulate an SSL connection. However, I'm not sure how to inject a mock or fake certificate into the ISslStreamFeature or the SSL stream itself.
What I've Tried

I've attempted to mock ISslStreamFeature using Moq, but I'm not sure how to configure the SslStream to include a fake certificate.

I also tried overriding the middleware, but didn't get the expected results.


What I'm Looking For

How can I fake or mock the LocalCertificate in the context of an ASP.NET Core integration test?

Is there a way to inject a certificate during test setup, or do I need to modify how my app handles certificates specifically for tests?


Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

I suggest you could check this article to test if this will work or not.

I managed to achieve this by creating a fake ISslStreamFeature using FakeItEasy and injecting it into the HttpContext using custom middleware.
Here’s how I did it:
Step 1: Creating the Fake ISslStreamFeature
First, I created a method to generate a fake ISslStreamFeature. This feature is required for handling SSL/TLS in ASP.NET Core, and by using FakeItEasy, I could mock its behavior.
private static ISslStreamFeature CreateFakeSslStreamFeature()
{
    var fakeCertificate = FakeCertificate.CreateFakeCertificate();
    using var fakeSslStream = new FakeSslStream(fakeCertificate);
    
    // Create a fake ISslStreamFeature using FakeItEasy
    var fakeSslStreamFeature = A.Fake<ISslStreamFeature>();
    
    // Set up the fake to return our fake SslStream when accessed
    A.CallTo(() => fakeSslStreamFeature.SslStream).Returns(fakeSslStream);

    return fakeSslStreamFeature;
}

FakeCertificate.CreateFakeCertificate() is used to generate a fake SSL certificate for the test.
FakeSslStream is a fake SSL stream that simulates the behavior of an actual SslStream for testing purposes.
A.Fake() creates a fake ISslStreamFeature object using FakeItEasy.
I set up the fake to return the fakeSslStream when the SslStream property is accessed.
Step 2: Injecting the Fake Feature into HttpContext Using Middleware
Next, I created a middleware that takes the fake ISslStreamFeature and injects it into the HttpContext. This ensures that when the application processes a request, the fake SSL stream feature is used.
Here’s the middleware:
public class CustomHttpContextMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    private readonly ISslStreamFeature sslStreamFeature;

    public CustomHttpContextMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ISslStreamFeature sslStreamFeature)
    {
        this.next = next;
        this.sslStreamFeature = sslStreamFeature;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        // Guard clause to ensure httpContext is not null
        ArgumentGuard.ThrowIfNull(httpContext, nameof(httpContext));
        
        // Inject the fake SSL feature into HttpContext
        httpContext.Features.Set(this.sslStreamFeature);

        // Continue processing the request
        await this.next(httpContext).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

The middleware takes a RequestDelegate and the ISslStreamFeature as dependencies.
In the InvokeAsync method, I inject the fake ISslStreamFeature into the HttpContext.Features collection. This makes the fake available to any part of the application that needs it.
The await this.next(httpContext) ensures that the next middleware in the pipeline is called.
Step 3: Applying the Middleware
Finally, I added the middleware to my ASP.NET Core pipeline by passing the fake ISslStreamFeature like this:
app.UseMiddleware<CustomHttpContextMiddleware>(fakeSslStreamFeature);

This ensures that every HTTP request going through the pipeline has the fake SSL stream feature available in its HttpContext.

My question is: this works with Kestrel but not with IIS. What can I do for IIS?

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

this code worked in IIS:
Explanation of the Code:
Obtaining Host and Port:
var host = context.Request.Host.Host;
var port = context.Request.Host.Port ?? 44318;
Here, you're getting the host (hostname) from the HTTP request context using context.Request.Host.Host. If the port isn't explicitly specified, you're defaulting it to 44318. This would typically be a fallback to a port used by the server.
Creating a TCP Client and Establishing SSL:
using (var client = new TcpClient(host, port))
{
   using (var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new 
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate!), 
        null))
   {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host);
        localCertificate = sslStream.RemoteCertificate as 
        X509Certificate2;
   }
}

A TcpClient is being created that connects to the specified host and port.
Then, an SslStream is created using the network stream from the TCP client.
SslStream allows you to securely communicate using SSL/TLS by encrypting data.
The second parameter (false) specifies that you won't need to leave the stream open after the SslStream is disposed.
You're passing in a RemoteCertificateValidationCallback delegate (ValidateServerCertificate!) that will handle validation of the server's certificate.
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(host) authenticates the client to the server, initiating an SSL/TLS handshake.
Finally, you're obtaining the remote server's certificate (sslStream.RemoteCertificate) and casting it to X509Certificate2.
Certificate Validation Callback:
private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, 
X509Certificate? certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors 
sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if (certificate == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true; // No errors, certificate is valid
    }

    return false;
}

This callback function is used during the SSL handshake to validate the server's certificate.
If no certificate is received (certificate == null), the validation fails, returning false.
If no SSL policy errors are found (SslPolicyErrors.None), the validation is considered successful (true).
Otherwise, if any errors are present, it returns false, rejecting the certificate.
